# Golang custom JSON unmarshalling

Tags: json, go

I am working with JSON whose structure I may not always know. Unmarshalling the data into `map[string]any` hence is the most appropriate for my use case. Now the issue is if there's any numeric value in the JSON data, `json.Unmarshal` converts it into `float64` which is problematic because I may loose precision if the value is actually an integer. Thus when unmarshalling I want the value to be of type `int64` in the map when possible but there doesn't seem to be an easy to accomplish this. What should be my approach to solve this?

Comment: Use `json.Decoder` with `UseNumber`. That will preserve JSON numbers as `json.Number`. Then you can convert them to whatever you need.

Comment: "which is problematic because I may loose precision if the value is actually an integer." Can you explain why you think this is true? Are you concerned about integers not representable by float64? If so: Why do you encode these as JSON numbers?

Answer (score 0):

A `float64` is a [64-bit IEEE 754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) type.  The internal representation of this type exactly represents integers in the range -2^53 to 2^53, so you only need be concerned if the integers in your problem domain lie outside this range.

That is: −9,007,199,254,740,992 to 9,007,199,254,740,992

You may be trying to solve a non-problem. :)